# Recording a http asx video stream on Ubuntu/Linux command line

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming

I've read several of the other questions here and other pages on the web, but so far nothing I've tried has worked.

The video I'm trying to cache for offline viewing is this lecture:

http://stanford-online.stanford.edu/courses/ee380/120118-ee380-300.asx

I've tried:

- using VLC to Stream to a file

  - if I disable transcoding, the resulting file is always 44KB.
  - if I enable transcoding, the resulting file is not playable!  (Despite being ID'd as a MPEG4 by `file`)
- using `mplayer -dumpstream` (also tried on the .wmv URL contained within the .asx)

  - I just get a bunch of "Stream not seekable! Stream not seekable! Stream dump complete."

I'm looking for a way to do this from the command line.

Totem has no problem just playing the stream, so I assume a way to dump the stream to a file is not out of reach, but I can't figure it out.

Anybody else able to record this?  Thanks in advance.

**Update**: I was wrong on one data point - if I enable transcoding in VLC, the resulting file *is* playable (just have to wait for the whole thing to complete - it was the partial recording that was not playable).  However, I'm still interested in a command-line approach to this problem, so that I can batch up many lectures.

Answer (score -1):

There's one particular cli software that gets flash videos https://code.google.com/p/get-flash-videos/ but it doesn't work with Stanford's site & asx

Maybe you could ask for support on the https://code.google.com/p/get-flash-videos/issues/list

Moreover, I tried Firefox's FlashGot & it was able to grab a .wmv link but that didn't work; the file was 187KB.

In case you find a solution, please write back.